# How to go the respective activity after clicking option in slide menu

Tags: android

ppl am trying to do menu option...and i got it,but after clicking the option in the slide menu...the control should go the respective page..i tried ..but its not working..please help me

```
    switch(position){
        case '0': {
            startActivity(new Intent(home.this, home.class));
            finish();
        }
        case '1':
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(home.this, info_values.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: why '0' is in single quotes?

Comment: what is the data type for `position`?

Comment: I think it should be 0 and 1 without quotes(if position is integer)

Comment: datatype is integer

Comment: add your all code of activity

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this

```
switch(position){
    case 0: 
        startActivity(new Intent(home.this, home.class));
        finish();
        break;
    case 1:

        startActivity(new Intent(home.this, info_values.class));
        finish();
        break;
    default:
        break;

}
```

Comment: hey ppl thank u..its working....but the problem is the control goes to  the same page

Comment: You are calling the intent same @shwettha `new Intent(home.this, home.class)` change the intent class name accordingly

Comment: whatever i give...the control always goes to info_values

Comment: Are you sure the position value is changing for each selection. @shwettha

Comment: then comment the `finish()` statement for the case 0. @shwettha

Comment: same..!!its not going to respective pages

Comment: Can you post you complete code, so that i can have a closer look? @shwettha

Comment: hey..thnak you...i will post the code for slide menu

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 'R.id.a':
                 startActivity(new Intent(home.this, home.class)); 

            case 'R.id.b':
                startActivity(new Intent(home.this,   info_values.class));
        }
        return true;
    }
```